# how can I delete the remnants of windows from a new CentOS 7 server?

Tags: centos, terminal, mount, partition, windows

I recently installed CentOS 7 on a new computer that came shipped with Windows 8.1.  The BIOS no longer shows windows as a boot option.  But my initial analysis of the file system is hard to interpret, and looks like there is still Microsoft data in a large portion of the machine.  **How can I eliminate the remnants of windows?  And how can I understand the availability and mountability of drives on the machine?**

Here is what I have done so far:

When I navigate to the `/` directory and type `du -ch | grep total`, the result is `851 MB` in the `/` directory.

Still in `/`, when I type in `df -h`, I get:

[image]

This seems to indicate that there are 4 partitions:

```
/dev/sda1    mounted on   /
/dev/sda2    mounted on   /boot
/dev/sda3    mounted on   /boot/efi
/dev/sda4    mounted on   /home
```

Given that two are boot partitions, it seems that the CentOS is on `/dev/sda4` and that the `/dev/sda3` partition is empty.  However, when I type in `fdisk -l`, I get very different results, as follows:

[image]

Here it seems that partitions 2, 3, and 4 are all Microsoft, though partition 4 is most likely `/dev/sda4` and `partition 3` is most likely `/dev/sda3`.

**Can someone please explain the partitions that are shown?  And can someone please explain how to eliminate what is left of Microsoft, so that all the partitions are clean, and in a format that can be used by CentOS?**

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have your `/dev/sdX` numbers mixed up between your screenshot and your summary.

Hence, the four partitions from `df` are

```
/dev/sda4    mounted on   /
/dev/sda2    mounted on   /boot
/dev/sda1    mounted on   /boot/efi
/dev/sda3    mounted on   /home
```

`/dev/sda1` is not empty; `df` shows it contains 191M.

`Type: Microsoft basic` in the partition table refers to the format *type*, not the content, i.e. something like `FAT`. If you look at the sizes, they appear to correlate with the `df` output, with the exception of 477M vs. 500M for `/dev/sda2`. I'm not sure why this minor discrepancy. Also, the swap partition is not listed in `df` (but viewable with something like `cat /proc/swaps`).

Hence, it looks like there is no Windows install on this hard drive. However, many of your partitions are in a Windows format.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to look from the outside ie put the hdd offline.
Any live-cd containing a version of parted or fdisk will do.
Easiest is probably gparted at gparted.org

Comment: What additional information will that give you?